# VBA - move row if cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way with VBA that the row in specific range moves if i change the value in a specific row?

In the picture you can see my table:

[image]

Dates in Range A4:B7 are in German Format (DD.MM.YYYY) and the header labels in Range D3:O3 is just text format.

So when i change for example in B5 the value to 01.12.2019 i would like that the cells in this row where moved from E5:H5 to L5:O5.

This is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If Target.Address = "$B$3:" & lastrow Then
        Call Mymacro
    End If
End Sub
```

But i don´t really know how i have to write the macro. I hope someone can help me. Thanks

**EDIT:**

Could solve it. Thanks to all who tried to help :)

Here is my code i use now.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim DelRng As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim rngyear As Range
    Dim rngmonth As Range

    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim year As String
    Dim month As String

    Dim FAA As Integer
    Dim MFG As Integer
    Dim AGA As Integer

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set KeyCells = Range("H11:H" & lastrow)

    year = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "yyyy")
    month = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "mmm")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Set DelRng = Range("N" & Target.Row & ":BI" & Target.Row)
        DelRng.ClearContents

        Set rngyear = ActiveSheet.Range("N1:BI1").Find(What:=year, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not rngyear Is Nothing Then
            Set rngmonth = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Target.Row, rngyear.Column), Cells(2, rngyear.Column + 11)).Find(What:=month, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not rngmonth Is Nothing Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, rngmonth.Column).Value = "DEL"
                If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Target.Row)) Then
                    FAA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, rngmonth.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 1
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, faa).Value = "FAA"
                End If
                If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Target.Row)) Then
                    MFG = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, rngmonth.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 2
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, faa3).Value = "MFG"
                End If
                If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Target.Row)) Then
                    AGA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, rngmonth.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 3
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, faa2).Value = "AGA"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If lastRow is 7 are you looking for `$B$37` ?

Comment: Are those (e.g. 01.12.2019) real dates in a non-EN-US format? What about the column header labels in D3:O3, are they 1/1/2018 formatted as mmm or are they text labels that are useless for lookup?

Comment: Wait, is it always those 4 items, and you  just need to figure out the first column to start in? Because if so I am reasonably sure it can be done with a formula and no vba.

Comment: This code to me looks very odd... Like @Jeeped said; why is Mymacro executed when your changed cell is B37? In your question you talk about changing B5. So what does your code have to do with your question?

Comment: I also agree with @JeremyKahan, it seems that if you format your data well enough this can be done through formula's instead. If you don't know how to write VBA this could be your way forward.

Comment: Sorry guys, i just forgot the dopple colon (Changed it now). In Range D3:O3 it is just text. @JeremyKahan yes it is always those 4 items.

Comment: so for instance if in D7 to O7 you had a formula like =if(COLUMN()=value(mid($B7,4,2)),"AGA",""), that would get you the first entry in the right place.

Comment: @JeremyKahan No i am not using a formula in the table. In fact my whole data has a VBA Code which adds the rows and the 4 items to the table. I thought this would not be necessary but I will post tomorrow (out of office right now) my whole data and hope that you/someone can help me with this to solve my problem.

Comment: Oh, so if you are writing in VBA anyway, then you are correct copying (or really moving, or calculating) could make sense. This was getting ugly anyway: =if(COLUMN()=value(mid($B1,4,2)),"AGA",if(COLUMN()-1=value(mid($B1,4,2)),"MFG",if(COLUMN()-2=value(mid($B1,4,2)),"FAA",if(COLUMN()-3=value(mid($B1,4,2)),"DEL",""))))